# In netflix TV show "Mindhunter", how does the "shoe" killer communicate with Ed?

Tags: mindhunter-2017

In Netflix TV show "Mindhunter", Holden and Tench go around and interview serial killers:

1. The very first killer they brain-pick is Ed, who is very chatty and befriend with the two FBI agents somewhat.
2. Another serial killer they interview is aggressive and in denial of all his convictions, by the end of their first interview, he says something similar to"Ed told me you guys are idiots and you must have suck every single line from him"; which heavily suggests Ed and this shoe-killer have been talking.

Maybe I missed something but how they manage to talk to each other? As convicted serial killers, their communication must be closely watched, including phone calls and letters, letting alone this shoe-killer would not have learnt Ed had been interviewed through an official channel.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe I missed something but how they manage to talk to each other?

This is shown to be plausible from two separate conversations:

- (1) When Ed Kemper & Holden meet for the first time; and
- (2) When Holden & Jerry Brudos meet for the first time.

---

When Ed and Holden begin talking, Ed immediately boasts about how great his relationship is with the guards, and is quite eager to demonstrate it. He does so by getting Holden an egg salad sandwich, and goes on to say that he's been at that prison for five years, and that the guards like him because he's polite. Also, Ed claims that the guards can talk to him better than they can talk to their own wives.

Given this, it's quite possible that Ed could asks favors of some of the guards that he has the best rapport with, and which may involve passing notes to other inmates (i.e., communicate with other prisons).

---

When Holden and Tench meet with Brudos, the following is said:

> BRUDOS: BIG ED with his big mouth; I bet you swallowed every ****ing line that came out of him, and he must have loved it.
>
> TENCH: Wait a minute, as far as I know, all of his communication is monitored..
>
> BRUDOS: What can I say? Prisons are like knitting circles, word gets around. (begins laughing)

---

With both of these conversations taken into consideration, I don't think it's too much of a stretch to think that Ed Kemper could [fairly easily] communicate with inmates at other prisons, of which may have involved simply mentioning that a couple of guys have been interviewing him, and then Brudos putting the two together (should Ed not have mentioned their names).